# Error when launching tasks with multiple arguments from UI spring cloud dataflow

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have a batch job with takes 2 parameters. when I pass these arguments while running the jar file directly, it works. Also when i pass these arguments via the shell of the spring cloud dataflow it works:

```
dataflow:>task launch --name adv-load --arguments "appnexus_seat=SEAT_MIQ_1 last_modified=2018/08/10"
Launched task 'adv-load'
```

But when I pass the similar arguments while running the task form the UI, it fails. Example, In the UI, i passed: appnexus_seat & last_modified as 2 keys with the same values as above but a different date so that it doesnt think its the same job. This failed.

I did however manage to find the issue. When i run the task via shell, in the logs I get this:

```
2018-09-21 14:04:50.970  INFO 4035 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: [appnexus_seat=SEAT_MIQ_1, last_modified=2018/08/10, --spring.cloud.task.executionid=5]
2018-09-21 14:04:51.073  INFO 4035 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=advertiserLoadJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{appnexus_seat=SEAT_MIQ_1, -spring.cloud.task.executionid=5, last_modified=2018/08/10}]
2018-09-21 14:04:51.081  INFO 4035 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.b.l.TaskBatchExecutionListener   : The job execution id 5 was run within the task execution 5
2018-09-21 14:04:51.116  INFO 4035 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [advertiserLoadStep1]
```

Whereas when i run it via the Ui i get this:

```
2018-09-21 14:05:57.417  INFO 4924 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: [appnexus_seat=SEAT_MIQ_1,last_modified=2018/08/10, --spring.cloud.task.executionid=6]
2018-09-21 14:05:57.518  INFO 4924 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=advertiserLoadJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{appnexus_seat=SEAT_MIQ_1,last_modified=2018/08/10, -spring.cloud.task.executionid=6}]
2018-09-21 14:05:57.528  INFO 4924 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.b.l.TaskBatchExecutionListener   : The job execution id 6 was run within the task execution 6
2018-09-21 14:05:57.586  INFO 4924 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [advertiserLoadStep1]
2018-09-21 14:05:57.653 ERROR 4924 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step advertiserLoadStep1 in job advertiserLoadJob

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.advertiserLoadTasklet': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mediaiq.appnexus.load.client.AppnexusRestClient com.mediaiq.appnexus.batch.tasklet.AbstractPageLoadTasklet.appnexusClient; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'JOB' defined in class path resource [com/mediaiq/appnexus/load/config/AppnexusRestClientFactory.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.mediaiq.appnexus.value.AppnexusSeat]: : Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.mediaiq.appnexus.value.AppnexusSeat]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.mediaiq.appnexus.value.AppnexusSeat]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.mediaiq.appnexus.value.AppnexusSeat]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.mediaiq.appnexus.value.AppnexusSeat]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

If you look at the difference you can see that when i run it via the shell it gives a space between the 2 arguments whereas when i run it via the Ui its doesn't. Not giving this space results in an issue as the value of the first argument becomes "SEAT_MIQ_1,last_modified=2018/08/10" instead of just being "SEAT_MIQ_1" and last_modified being another argument.

Please let me know how to resolve this. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the task from the UI, you need to specify each argument in a separate field:

[image]

This will correctly pass parameters to your task.

Comment: Hey, I have been doing exactly that. Still, it has not been adding a space between arguments but only a comma.

Comment: I tested my answer with version 1.7.0.M1 and it works fine. Which version of spring cloud data flow are you using?

Comment: dataflow server: 1.6.3

Comment: Also, when you're running your job with params can you please show me the logs of the execution where it shows you the command line args and job parameters taken? Thanks

Comment: My task is actually a hello world Spring Batch job that takes 2 parameters `name1` and `name2` and prints: `Hello name1 name2`. Here is the command in the log: `2018-09-21 13:47:41.996  INFO 3982 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job]] launched with the following parameters: [{name2=bar, -spring.cloud.task.executionid=1, name1=foo}]`. I just tested with version 1.6.3.RELEASE and it works as expected too.

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot. I also tried using v1.7.0.M1 and it worked. I guess it's a bug with the current version. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - How can we always pass the Unique Task Argument programmatically ? This is needed when we run Task through SCDF UI. Any pointers ? Here is original Q : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271924/a-job-instance-already-exists-and-is-complete-for-parameters-spring-cloud-task/61272274#61272274