# A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={-spring.cloud.task.executionid=2}. If you want to run this job again, change the parame

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I am working on `Spring Cloud Data Flow and Spring Batch` by taking a reference from https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/tree/master/spring-cloud-task-samples.

I'm executing the batch-job and when executed this example two times, on 2nd time I observed the error, however for the first time it worked fine.

I started the `spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local` server using below commands and it created all metadata for me- highlighted in yellow.

Error:

```
exitCode=null, taskName='batch-job', startTime=Fri Apr 17 18:21:36 IST 2020, endTime=null, exitMessage='null', externalExecutionId='null', errorMessage='null', arguments=[--spring.cloud.task.executionid=3]}
2020-04-17 18:21:36.312  INFO 4988 --- [           main] com.example.BatchJobApplication          : Started BatchJobApplication in 3.661 seconds (JVM running for 4.407)
2020-04-17 18:21:36.312  INFO 4988 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: [--spring.cloud.task.executionid=3]
2020-04-17 18:21:36.396 DEBUG 4988 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.r.support.SimpleTaskRepository   : Updating: TaskExecution with executionId=3 with the following {exitCode=1, endTime=Fri Apr 17 18:21:36 IST 2020, exitMessage='null', errorMessage='java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:787)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.example.BatchJobApplication.main(BatchJobApplication.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={-spring.cloud.task.executionid=3}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBe'}
2020-04-17 18:21:36.404  INFO 4988 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar
```

[image]

On the second time Task Execution, I get the below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:787) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.BatchJobApplication.main(BatchJobApplication.java:14) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [batch-job-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [batch-job-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [batch-job-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [batch-job-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={-spring.cloud.task.executionid=2}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:131) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:181) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.createJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:137) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:192) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:166) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:153) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:148) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted

2020-04-17 17:35:47.076  INFO 10780 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-04-17 17:35:47.091  INFO 10780 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

[image]

[image]

BatchJobApplication.java

```
@EnableTask
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchJobApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BatchJobApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addDate("date", new Date())
                .addLong("JobId",System.currentTimeMillis())
                .addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();

        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        System.out.println("STATUS :: "+execution.getStatus());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolved this issue, I passed the unique key:value in the Task Argument and I so keeping passing the multiple key:value combinations, then I can run the same Task many times.

However I wanted to do this programmatically. Any quick solution ?

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(JobConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job job1() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job1").start(this.stepBuilderFactory.get("job1step1").tasklet(new Tasklet() {
            @Override
            public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                logger.info("Job1 was run");
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }
        }).build()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job2() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job2").start(this.stepBuilderFactory.get("job2step1").tasklet(new Tasklet() {
            @Override
            public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                logger.info("Job2 was run");
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }
        }).build()).build();
    }
}
```

Great Help from @GlennRenfro - Use `.incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).` in each job, now you can execute the same job multiple times.

[image]

Comment: You could pass a task argument in code to your batch job, key would be something like ‘timestamp’ and value can be Instant.NOW, that way you will assure unique value each time a job is run

Comment: Could you please show code or link how to do this  ?

Comment: where you have your jobLauncher.run() method, you need to pass Job instance and JobParameters, right? so you can use JobParametersBuilder() helper to create these params. Example:

JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addString("param1, "value1")
                    .addString("param2, "value2")
                    .addString("param3, "value3")
                    .addLong("timestamp", Instant.now().toEpochMilli())
                    .toJobParameters();

Comment: Hey these all parameters I m already passing, the issue is that somehow I would need to pass unique `Arguments  --spring.cloud.task.executionid: 2` each time, I hope this clarifies now

Comment: can you please show me the code base where your run() method is invoked?

Comment: hey, added the main class

Comment: I usually don't put multiple jobs in the same application.   But that aside you can add a job incrementer if you need to launch a job multiple times.
  return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("myjob")
    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
    .start(mystep)
    .build();

Comment: Ah, Ok, I will try and let you know.

Comment: @GlennRenfro - Thanks, I kept single job and used `.incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())` with the Job, seems like it working fine now. How can we execute multiple Jobs one after the another using Spring Cloud Task or what's the best way ?

Comment: I think you are asking about workflows, i.e. run task-1 then task-2 then task-3.   Take a look at Spring Cloud Data Flow's Composed tasks.   More information can be read about it here: https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/feature-guides/batch/composed-task/

Comment: Ah, Ok, here the catch is, you need to create multiple projects and create a individual jar out of it to import it into Task maven, am I right ? Having all jobs in a single jar is issue

Comment: Not necessarily.  You can have multiple jobs in a single jar and each job is configured by a spring profile.   And for each task in the workflow (composed task) would have a specific profile active (using the spring.profiles.active set via the command line) allowing a single job to launched.

Comment: Ah, great Knowledge, do you've sample on how we can do this? Please ?

Comment: Not one off hand, but there is serveral articles on spring profiles.