# SCDF + Spring Batch : JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={run.id=1}

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

SCDF is launching job as:

```
Command to be executed: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el7_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java -jar /opt/scdf-batches/foo/foo-1.0.26.jar --spring.cloud.task.executionid=23
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:785) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at com.example.FooSsapApplication.main(FooSsapApplication.java:29) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={run.id=1}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:136) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:181) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy150.createJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:137) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy152.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:199) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Batch Code:

```
    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get("Foo")
                .<Long, Long>chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(fooReader())
                .processor(fooProcessor())
                .writer(fooWriter())
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .build();

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("FooJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener())
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }
```

looking at [A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={-spring.cloud.task.executionid=2}. If you want to run this job again, change the parame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271924/a-job-instance-already-exists-and-is-complete-for-parameters-spring-cloud-task) response, modified the code, but seems its not working.

I am using Spring Boot 2.4.1 and SCDF - 2.7.1

Comment: also tried below, but still doesn't help
```
JobParametersIncrementer runIncrementer = new RunIdIncrementer();
  runIncrementer.getNext(new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters());

  return jobBuilderFactory.get("FooJob")
    .incrementer(runIncrementer)
    .listener(listener())
    .start(step)
    .build();
```

Comment: Since you defined a job parameters incrementer, you should have a new job instance on each run. So I don't see how you ended up in this situation. Please provide a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you.